# Topological/geometric interpretation of conjugacy separability

Tags: group-theory

We say that a group $G$ is residually finite if for every non-trivial $g \in G$ there is a a finite group $Q$ and a surjective homomorphism $\phi \colon G \to Q$ such that $\phi(g) \neq_Q 1$.

This has a nice topological interpretation: when $G = \pi_1(X)$ is residually finite then for every non-conctractible loop $\gamma$ in $X$ there is a finite-sheeted cover of $X$ that opens $\gamma$. Or equivalently, we can say that for every compact subset of the universal cover $K \subseteq \tilde{X}$ there is a finite-sheeted cover of $X$ in which the projection from $\tilde{X}$ is embedding when restricted to $K$.

My question is: is there some similarly nice interpretation of conjugacy separability?

Note that a group $G$ is conjugacy separable if for every tuple $f,g \in G$ such that $f \not\sim_G g$ there is a finite group $Q$ and a surjection $\phi \colon G \to Q$ such that $\phi(f) \not\sim_Q \phi(G)$, where the symbol $\sim_G$ denotes the relation of being conjugate in group $G$.